# how to draw a line on label text in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As shown in the image below I need to draw a line dynamically on a label text. Here is my label in listview

[image]

Can anyone please tell me about this?

Comment: Set TextDecorations Property of Label to StrikeThrough as I answered I answered here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54088898/6577892

Answer (score 9):

Here you go, you can make your own control (strikedLabel) and place this code. To make it more fun and flexiable  you can add bindable properties like (IsStriked, StrikeColor, etc...) , remember that order between the label and the BoxView is important

```
<Grid>
    <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Sample string" />
    <BoxView HeightRequest="3"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    Opacity="0.5"
    Color="Aqua" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 9):

I think rather than implementing it with different layouts or box view we can simply use TextDecorations property for Label provided by Xamarin like below.

```
<Label
      Text="$200"
      TextDecorations="Strikethrough" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Xamarin.Forms doesn't provide this functionality out of the box, you'll need to extend the Label by creating a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) for each platform. By doing that you can access the native controls on each platform([TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) on Android and [UILabel](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel) on iOS) and implement the strikethrough effect there.

1. On Android, you [STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) on the TextView. You need something like this in the custom renderer: `someTextView.PaintFlags = Paint.StrikeThruText;`
2. On iOS, you should follow the guidance from [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11584/how-to-add-strikeout-strikethrough-to-an-uilabel) on Xamarin forums. Basically, you use [UIStringAttributes](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIStringAttributes/) to achieve the desired results.

If you're new to custom renderers, take a look at the getting started tutorial on how to customize the Entry control [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry/).

---

Edit: Actually, you might even be able to pull this off using an Effect. More information [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/introduction/).

Comment: Note: should be `someTextView.PaintFlags = PaintFlags.StrikeThruText;` `PaintFlags` is the proper enum to reference, not `Paint`

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple to use Effect do following steps:

**Xaml**

```
<Label Text="{Binding TotalReatilAmount}" >
    <Label.Effects>
        <Helpers:LineThroughEffect />
    </Label.Effects>
</Label>
```

Don't forget to put below line in XAML header

```
xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace.Helpers"
```

Create one class inheriting from RoutingEffect

```
public class LineThroughEffect : RoutingEffect
    {    
        public LineThroughEffect() : base("MyNameSpace.Helpers.PlatformLineThroughEffect") { }
    }
```

Create render for Platform Specific

**iOS**

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("MyNameSpace.Helpers")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(PlatformLineThroughEffect), nameof(PlatformLineThroughEffect))]
namespace MyNameSpace.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class PlatformLineThroughEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            SetUnderline(true);
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            SetUnderline(false);
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(args);

            if (args.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName ||
                args.PropertyName == Label.FormattedTextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetUnderline(true);
            }
        }

        private void SetUnderline(bool underlined)
        {
            try
            {
                var label = (UILabel)Control;
                if (label != null)
                {
                    var text = (NSMutableAttributedString)label.AttributedText;
                    if (text != null)
                    {
                        var range = new NSRange(0, text.Length);
                        if (underlined)
                        {
                            text.AddAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.StrikethroughStyle,
                                NSNumber.FromInt32((int)NSUnderlineStyle.Single), range);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            text.RemoveAttribute(UIStringAttributeKey.StrikethroughStyle, range);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Track();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what about the Android?

Answer (score 1):

[Text decorations property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#text-decorations) do this easily. you just have to set this property.

```
<Label Text="This is text with strikethrough." TextDecorations="Strikethrough" />
```

But if you want to this dynamically during the runtime than you have to binding this property.

There is a [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) interface at xamarin that you can use for this. You can create a converter like below:

```
  public class StatusToTextDecoration : IValueConverter
   {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var decorationText = TextDecorations.None;
        if (value == null) return decorationText;

        if (System.Convert.ToInt32(value) == MyStatus) decorationText = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;

        return decorationText;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //For this case you can ignore this
        return null;
    }
   }
```

and than just you have to add this converter to your xaml page as reference:

```
xmlns:converterLocal="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converter;assembly=MyApp"
```

and set as a resource at top of your page after references:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <converterLocal:StatusToTextDecoration x:Key="StatusToTextDecoration"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And here you go , just set your converter at your label than :

```
<Label Text="This is text with strikethrough." TextDecorations="{Binding MyStateId, Converter={StaticResource StatusToTextDecoration}}" />
```

than it will set text decoration according the valur of your "MyStateId" field at data source.

Comment: How can I combine this with a checkbox ischecked property to change the label?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding my Android side implementation to this answer. I adapted it from this article: https://smstuebe.de/2016/08/29/underlinedlabel.xamarin.forms/

```
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Widget;
using MyNamespace.Core.CustomRenderers;
using MyNamespace.Droid.Library.ViewRenderers;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ResolutionGroupName(StrikethroughEffect.EffectNamespace)]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(StrikethroughEffectAndroid), nameof(StrikethroughEffect))]
namespace MyNamespace.Droid.Library.ViewRenderers
{
    public class StrikethroughEffectAndroid : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            RenderEffect(true);
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            RenderEffect(false);
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(args);

            if (args.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName || args.PropertyName == Label.FormattedTextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                RenderEffect(true);
            }
        }

        private void RenderEffect(bool shouldApply)
        {
            try
            {
                var textView = (TextView)Control;
                if (shouldApply)
                {
                    textView.PaintFlags |= PaintFlags.StrikeThruText;
                }
                else
                {
                    textView.PaintFlags &= ~PaintFlags.StrikeThruText;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot strike-through Label. Error: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers!